# Sorting formatted (colored) text

Tags: bash

I'm trying to format colored text in bash. I have the follow data:

```
\e[32m05 Jul 2019 18:54:05,452 [INFO] ced72f28-3737-4886-98fc-ea5c3f42530d 
\e[33m05 Jul 2019 18:19:04,709 [INFO] 44e39b97-fb72-41bc-8c5c-780f63721a2f
```

Im trying to sort the rows on `Jul 2019 18:54:05,452` Before adding colour, I was able to successfully accomplish this by doing `sort -n -t [ -k 1` . Does anyone have any suggestions to bypass the colour text before sorting?

Comment: Why not just using space as the separator `sort -t' ' -k2,4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like that?

```
sort -k1.9 file.txt
```

**explanation**

Start sort at position 9 of first keyword.

Comment: This works but im not quite sure how/why. Can you help me understand how -k1.9 works ? Thanks

Comment: `-k1.9` --> the sorting starts from the ninth character within the first key.